# Could I style a link depending on the get-parameters of a URL with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, url, css-selectors, query-string

So let's say the URL in the browser's address line is either
`http://example.com/test.html?res=sun` or 
`http://example.com/test.html?res=water` or 
`http://example.com/test.html?res=tree`

And for all those three there are always the three links on the page.
`<a href="http://example.com/test.html?res=sun">sun</a>`
`<a href="http://example.com/test.html?res=water">water</a>`
`<a href="http://example.com/test.html?res=tree">tree</a>`

I want the one link that is matched by the current address line to be highleighted by another background, while the other two links shouldn't be highlighted.

Is this possible? Could I place the style directive directly in the `<a>`-tag, or does the directives have to be in the `<style>`-tag as classes and every `<a>`-tag has to have the appropriate class added then?

Comment: So you want to apply a set of CSS rules based on the current address? Apart from `:target`, which is not applicable here, this is not possible. You could inset a rule by JavaScript with the selector `"a[href*='" + location.split("?")[1] + "']"` or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, it's not possible.

Long answer: There used to be a `:local-link` proposal in Selectors 4 that would do exactly what you're looking for (albeit not with query string-specific behavior, but still suitable for the use case you describe), but it was deferred to level 5 a few years ago for unknown reasons. Considering level 4 itself isn't stabilizing anytime soon, any features not still in it are as good as not happening.